# How To Find Complex Roots of A Multivariate Polynomial Equation System (Python)

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers, polynomial-math, equation-solving

Consider following equation system:

```
1623.66790917 * x ** 2 + 468.829686367 * x * y + 252.762128419 * y ** 2 + -1027209.42116 * x + -301192.975791 * y + 188804356.212 = 0

11154.1759415 * x ** 2 + 31741.0229155 * x * y + 32933.5622632 * y ** 2 + -16226174.4037 * x + -26323622.7497 * y + 6038609721.67 = 0
```

As you see there are two pairs of complex solutions to the system. I tried `sympy` but it was not a success. I want to know how to figure it out in Python. BTW I don't have a nice initial guess to use numeric methods.

Comment: Those equations are probably effectively a quartic equation which while generally possible to solve symbolically it's the limit of the degree that can generally be solved symbolically. Perhaps you're looking for a numeric method?

Comment: @skyking A symbolic solution that reveals complex roots, is just nice. I tried sympy solve_poly_system but it took a long time without a solution.

Comment: You want to figure out the solution *for that particular* equation system?  But you already know it.  Presumably you mean some class of equation systems.  What class?

Comment: @strubbly not looking for a particular equation system. I want to find all four solution for an equation system, consisting of two equations for two conics that are co-planar circles under a projective homography. A pair of the solutions represent image of circular point (ICP) under the homography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve those equations numerically using mpmath's [findroot()](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.17/doc/build/calculus/optimization.html#mpmath.findroot). As far as I know there isn't a way to tell `findroot()` to find multiple roots, but we can get around that restriction: first, find a solution pair (xa, ya), then divide the equations by (x - xa)*(y - ya). You do have to supply an initial approximate solution, but I managed to find something that worked in only a few tries.

```
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 30
prec = 20

f_1 = lambda x, y: 1623.66790917 * x ** 2 + 468.829686367 * x * y + 252.762128419 * y ** 2 + -1027209.42116 * x + -301192.975791 * y + 188804356.212

f_2 = lambda x, y: 11154.1759415 * x ** 2 + 31741.0229155 * x * y + 32933.5622632 * y ** 2 + -16226174.4037 * x + -26323622.7497 * y + 6038609721.67

def solve(f1, f2, initxy):
    return mp.findroot([f1, f2], initxy, solver='muller')

def show(x, y):
    print 'x=', mp.nstr(x, prec)
    print 'y=', mp.nstr(y, prec)
    print mp.nstr(f_1(x, y), prec)
    print mp.nstr(f_2(x, y), prec)
    print

f1a = f_1
f2a = f_2
xa, ya = solve(f1a, f2a, (240+40j, 265-85j))
show(xa, ya)

f1b  = lambda x, y: f1a(x, y) / ((x - xa) * (y - ya))
f2b  = lambda x, y: f2a(x, y) / ((x - xa) * (y - ya))
xb, yb = solve(f1b, f2b, (290+20j, 270+30j))
show(xb, yb)
```

**output**

```
x= (246.82064795986653023 + 42.076841530787279711j)
y= (261.83565021239842638 - 81.555049135736951496j)
(0.0 + 3.3087224502121106995e-24j)
(0.0 + 0.0j)

x= (289.31873055121622967 + 20.548128321524345062j)
y= (272.23440694481666637 + 29.381152413744722108j)
(0.0 + 3.3087224502121106995e-24j)
(0.0 + 0.0j)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the sample code. As I commented on OP I want to find all four solution for an equation system, consisting of two equations for two conics. Those conics are co-planar circles under a projective homography. A pair of the solutions represent image of circular point (ICP) under the homography.
As mentioned in OP I don't have good estimation to start with. I'm looking for a more general approach that solves the equation system automatically.

Comment: @Bahribayli: Well, yeah, coming up with good initial estimations isn't easy. :) If you can create pairs of parametric equations for those conics then you could easily generate lists of points on the curves and then search for approximate matches in the lists; essentially plotting the curves in CxC and looking for points where they cross. OTOH, you may get acceptable results just by using randomly generated points that are in the region of the CxC "plane" covered by the conics.